# With Micronaut Data JDBC, how do I transform a value for WHERE clauses?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm using Micronaut Data JDBC 1.1.3 with a MySQL 8.0 database. I'd like to have my `id` columns use a `BINARY(16)` storage and use BIN_TO_UUID()/UUID_TO_BIN() to convert the values.  I though I could do this with Micronaut Data's `@ColumnTransformer`, like this:

```java
public class User {
    @Id
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "BIN_TO_UUID(user_.id)", write = "UUID_TO_BIN(?)")
    private UUID id;

    // ...
}
```

I then use a UserRepository like this:

```java
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.MYSQL)
public interface UserRepository extends RxJavaCrudRepository<User, UUID> {
}
```

It works great in that the `id` column is correctly tranformed in query results.  But when I try to find something by ID, using `userRepository.findById(id).toSingle()`, I get an error ("the MaybeSource is empty"), and I can see in the trace output the it is not tranforming the value:

```
15:17:04.878 [pool-1-thread-76] DEBUG io.micronaut.data.query - Executing Query: SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(user_.id) AS id,user_.`username` FROM `user` user_ WHERE (user_.`id` = ?)
```

---

Is this expected? Is there anything else I can do transform the query?  Do I have to write an explicit query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Micronaut-Data 1.1.3.

As a workaround I would override the query like:

```
@ReadOnly
@Override
@Query(
   "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id = :id")
Optional<User> findById(UUID id);
```

in the UserRepository interface.

BTW Query needs of cause to be customized for your needs.

Comment: Thank you Marc! I haven't yet gotten around to testing this, but will mark it as accepted as it looks right. :) Do you have any idea of there being a bug ticket somwhere I could follow?

Comment: @skagedal It's already fixed in micronaut data 2.0 here is the link to the [fix](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/commit/ab19a1acabcad9eb6a82cb533c8e61882947d972) which references to the bugticket. I've already upgraded and it works like a charm with uuid's.